# How to display calculations result in a hinted TextView in Android Studio/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple converter that will convert the amount given in dollars to euros.

This is my component tree:

id: button - onClick: convert

id: input - EditText

id: output - TextView

My output field (which its id is "output" as well) is a TextView because I don't want the user to be able to write in it. Unless I figure out a way to reverse the calculations which at this time I do not know how to do.

**My question is** how to display euroamount - which is the result of calculations - in the TextView field - which its id is "output"?

This is my code:

```
public void convert (View view){
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    Double usdamount = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
    Double euroamount = usdamount * 0.88;

    Log.i("input",input.getText().toString());
    Log.i("output",euroamount.toString());
}
```

Thank you very much!

PS: I am a beginner so extensive explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
output.setText(euroamount.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the first line, but what exactly does the second line do? It converts euroamount into a string then display it in the field whose id is output?

Comment: Yes. I have created an instance of `TextView` class called `output`. Then using the `setText()` method of `TextView` class, the data i.e. `euroamount` is first converted to string using `toString()` and then displayed. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you have any idea how to make the calculation works both ways? Enter USD and get the Euro amount and vice versa?

Comment: Glad to help you. Please upvote if it really helps you. Regarding your question, you can use 2 radio buttons and then perform your computation based on what is selected.

Comment: I did upvote but I don't have enough points for my votes to be visible yet. (: